# How to fix AsyncTask params error?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on a registration based project that uses asyncTask. But I am getting errors on its params and the background usage tasks.

Snippet -

```
public class signupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edit_name;
    EditText edit_usn;
    EditText edit_addnum;
    EditText edit_pass;
    EditText edit_repass;
    Button btn_sign;
private static final String REGISTER_URL="http://abcd.000webhostapp.com/signup.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_name);
        edit_usn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_usn);
        edit_addnum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_add);
        edit_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_pass);
        edit_repass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_repass);
        btn_sign=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btn_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String name=edit_name.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String usn=edit_usn.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String addnum=edit_addnum.getText().toString();
        String pass=edit_pass.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String repass=edit_repass.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        register(name, usn, addnum, pass, repass);
    }
private void register(String name,String usn,String addnum,String pass,String repass) {

    String urlsuffix = "?name=" + name + "&usn=" + usn + "&ddnum=" + addnum + "&pass=" + pass + "&repass=" + repass;

    //Getting **illegal start of type** for void keyword here
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask <String, void, String> implements abcd.project2.RegisterUser {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(signupActivity.this, "please wait", null, true, true);
        }

        //Getting **method does not override or implement a method from a supertype** for override here
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result = bufferReader.readLine();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    RegisterUser ur = new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlsuffix);
}
    public void openCreateList(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, createActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }}
```

Error messages -

> Error:(56, 50) error: illegal start of type
>  Error:(65, 9) error:
>   method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

How do I solve these? 
I tried changing the return type in params but still I am unable to solve the error.

Comment: write `Void` instead of `void` (Notice capital `V`)  in parameter

Comment: write Void instead of void

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Thanks for that. Didn't notice at all! How do I fix method does not override error?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for that. Didn't notice at all! How do I fix method does not override error?

Comment: @abhilnair I didn't get you!!

Comment: Change void v into uppercase V inside AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Comment: Methods will show override error because you have overrided them with older parameter types. there are 2 ways to fix it. 1) Manually change return type of override method or 2) remove your override method and again override it by pressing `alt+Enter`. I recommend to choose 2nd way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> 1. Its **`Void`** not **`void`** in parameter of `AsyncTask`
> 2. You need to change your **`onPostExecute()`** method just pass `String` parameter in `onPostExecute()` method

Change your code like below code

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
private void register(String name,String usn,String addnum,String pass,String repass) {

    String urlsuffix = "?name=" + name + "&usn=" + usn + "&ddnum=" + addnum + "&pass=" + pass + "&repass=" + repass;

    //Getting **illegal start of type** for void keyword here
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements abcd.project2.RegisterUser {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(signupActivity.this, "please wait", null, true, true);
        }

        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result = bufferReader.readLine();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    RegisterUser ur = new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlsuffix);
}
```

You can read more about [**`AsyncTask`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

1.Change void to Void

2.change your `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change word "void" to **Void** in the line of  `class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask <String, void, String> implements abcd.project2.RegisterUser`

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
   Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type `Void`:

   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask { ... }

   refer this [Official document site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) :